# Export Stack Exchange questions to Quora

Tags: stack-exchange, quora

I'm looking for a program (any OS is fine), script, browser plugin, web-service, or anything else that would allow me to easily export all my Stack Exchange questions to [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora).

Comment: Dosen't sound like something trivial. Assuming there's an export method (using the api?) you'd still need to re-import them

Comment: I hate to admit it – but there are already too many "clones" running around (many of them even forget to mention their origin), which makes finding *true* results via a web search difficult. With *Quora* I have my special reservations (as that even requires an account for *reading*) – so I have to agree with Mawg. </rant> But, @Mawg, that's the "political side" of it, and not to be discussed here; chat or Meta are better fitted for that. // Franck: Just the questions, or the answers & comments as well? Some background might also be helpful :)

Comment: Questions and answers. Too much [content deletion](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1116/903) here, need back up. (To read Quora content without signing in, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213726/178179))

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SE API](http://api.stackexchange.com) to export questions and answers for specific user, e.g.

- [`/users/{ids}/answers`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users)
- [`/users/{ids}/questions`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users)

or via query at [SE Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), like:

```
select * from posts where owneruserid=1234;​
```

alternatively you can extract such data from the [dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) using Torrent client (such as [BitTorrent](http://www.bittorrent.com/)).

Related:

- [Export My Stack Overflow Data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77331/191655) at Meta.SE
- [How to export all of my own answers into a text document?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194456/191655) at Meta.SE
- [How can I download my content from a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194475/191655) at Meta.SE
- [All Your Stack Posts](https://stackapps.com/q/4306/11890) (WordPress plugin) at StackApps